# USB-C to Micro-B converter does not support hardware that requires power supply

Tags: usb, power-supply, android, usb-c

I am trying to **connect a Micro-B physical keyboard to my tablet having USB-C port**. It is not working, although the keyboard is working fine on devices with Micro-B ports. 
To ensure that my USB-C to Micro-B converter is relaying (not sure if it is the correct term) power to the device/hardware, I tried to connect a charger using the converter, but it does not work. 
Is there any way to get it working?

Comment: Is it a gen 3+ micro-b or is it older? Also, do you have any other devices or converters to test if the converter is broken?

Comment: I am not sure about the Micro-b version but the converter is not broken. I have tested multiple Micro-B to Type C converters, but none have worked thus far.

Comment: You might try a hub instead of a cable.

Comment: *"It is not working"* -- That's just a summation, and not a description of what actually happens.  Does the keyboard seem to get power, e.g. do any LEDs blink?      The Micro-B connector has an extra pin to indicate (from the plug side) whether the OTG port should be in gadget mode (receiving power) or in host mode (providing power).  Describe the devices that the keyboard works with.  Do they have OTG ports or dedicated host micro-B ports?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your tablet has a Type-C DRP (dual-role port).

What you need is to turn the tablet's DRP into DFP - downstream-facing port. To make it happen, your Type-C plug must have a 5.1k resistor from CC1 pin to ground (better have 5.1k on both CC1 and CC2). This will make the dongle as a Type-C device, and the host (tablet) will recognize this, turn the port into USB host mode, and output ("relay") valid +5V voltage on VBUS. So your keyboard will get power and start working.

Now, what is inside your no-name "USB-C to Micro-B converter" is anyone's guess. But if you manage to find a "USB-C plug - to - Micro-AB receptacle", it will have much more chances that it has proper pull-down on CC pins. Alternatively, if you have a USB-C (plug) to micro-B (plug) CABLE, and your keyboard has micro-B receptacle, it should work right away.